# Access SVN server from machine on work subnet via an SSH tunnel

Tags: svn, ssh, tunnel

I'm attempting to access my work SVN server via an SSH tunnel to a separate machine.

Something like this:
(Local_Machine) -- SSH_Tunnel --> (Workstation) -- LAN --> (SVN_Server)

I can currently tunnel into my workstation via ssh, but cannot access the svn server via the tunnel on my local machine.

Is what I'm attempting to do possible, or do I need to also tunnel into the SVN_Server from the Workstation?

Further information :
Local machine is a Windows 7 box using putty to tunnel.
Workstation is another Windows 7 box using winsshd.
SVN_Server is a Windows Server 2008 box (No SSH access)

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint of a remote tunnel doesn't need to be on the same machine. So, you can set up a tunnel that goes from your local machine to the remote SVN server. This is how you might do that using the ssh command line:

```
ssh -L 3690:svn_server:3690 workstation
```

This connects to your SSH server on your workstation, and sets up a tunnel from local port 3690 to port 3690 on `svn_server`.

If you're already going through a tunnel to get to your workstation, you can embed the above tunnel inside the tunnel you've already got.