# How to connect to work SVN repository from home via SSH tunnel

Tags: svn, ssh, nat, tunnel

Apologies, but I have searched and read previous answers on this question but couldn't quite figure out how to solve my particular query. I think the following question was close but again I couldn't figure it out!

[Access SVN server from machine on work subnet via an SSH tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590764/access-svn-server-from-machine-on-work-subnet-via-an-ssh-tunnel)

My scenario:

At work I connect to an SVN repository on host **frodo** via svn protocol i.e. svn://frodo

I do not have SSH access to frodo.

My work PC is behind a NAT router and as such does not have public IP address. (It's IP is similar to 172.1.1.1)

I can however SSH from my work PC to my home PC, the hostname is **aruba.myexample.org**

Can I use SSH to connect **from** my work PC **to** my home PC and also forward to the SVN repo on frodo?

I used the SSH -L command to forward from my work PC to frodo, however I become stuck when trying to setup ports on my home PC (aruba.myexample.org)

I am sure it is possible?

TIA

Ayub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this `ssh -R 3690:frodo:3690 aruba.myexample.org`

Comment: When trying the above command I receive the error "Bad remote forwarding specification"

Comment: So to recap. On the work pc it was `ssh -R 3690:frodo:3690 aruba.myexample.org` and on my home PC to checkout from SVN I used `svn svn://localhost:3690/myexampleproject`